Bounding operator norm in terms of (generalised) Gram matrix singular values
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, and take $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|x_i\|=1$. Let $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be the (generalized) Gram matrix $G_{ij} = x_i^T A x_j$. Here, $A$ is an arbitrary square matrix, not positive definite or symmetric. Vectors $x_i$ are arbitrary, not necessarily linearly independent.
Can one lower-bound the spectral norm $\|A\|_2$ in terms of the nuclear norm $\|G\|_*$ (or similar) of $G$? Crucially, the bound should be not just in terms of $\|G\|_2$, but should be higher when there are many large singular values in G. [Edited:] A potential conjecture is: $$\|A\|_2 \geq \frac{\|G\|_*}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(G)}{n}$$
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

I can think of situations where $G =0$ but $A \ne 0$ and even $A$ is non-singular. Just consider  $A$ for which there is $x\ne 0$ with $x^TAx = 0$ and then take $x_i = x /|x|$ for all $i$.

Thanks! In this case, $|A|2 > 0 = |G|*$, and a lower bound of the kind conjectured is trivially true. Is this what you have in mind? [I've edited the original question with a concrete example conjecture]

Let $\|A\|_2$ and $\|A\|_{F}$ denote a matrix's spectral norm and the Frobenius norm, respectively.
Since the vectors $x_i$ are unit-normed, we have $\|Ax_i\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2$. By applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
 |\langle x_i, Ax_j \rangle | \leq \|A\|_2.
$$
This implies that the Frobenius norm of the matrix G satisfies
$$
\|G\|_{F}^2 = \sum_{i,j} |\langle x_i, Ax_j \rangle |^2 \leq n^2 \|A\|_{2}^2.
$$
Rearranging,
$$
\|A\|_2 \geq \frac{\|G\|_F}{n}.
$$
Since $\|G\|_2 \leq \|G\|_F$ holds for any matrix $G$, it also follows that
$$
\|A\|_2 \geq \frac{\|G\|_F}{n} \geq \frac{\|G\|_2}{n}.
$$

OP asked for the bound in terms of something other than the $2$-norm, but your bound holds for the Frobenius norm as well

Here is a proof attempt (thanks to Satwik for further discussion).
Proposition: Let $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be vectors with $\|x_i\|_2=1$, and let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ arbitrary. Let $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $G_{ij} = x_i^T A x_j$.
Then
\begin{equation}
    \|A\|_2 \geq \frac{\|G\|_*}{n}
\end{equation}
where $\|A\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm.
Proof:
First (I), note that for any matrix $B$ with SVD $B = U \Sigma V$, we have
\begin{equation}
    \|B\|_* = tr(\Sigma) = tr(\Sigma V V^T U^T U) = tr(U \Sigma V V^T U^T) = tr(BV^TU^T)
\end{equation}
where $V^TU^T$ is orthogonal.
Second (II), we use the following generalization of von Neumann's trace inequality:
\begin{equation}
    tr(B_1\dots B_k) \leq \sum_{i} \sigma_i(B_1) \dots \sigma_i(B_k)
\end{equation}
This is shown in H.2 (eq. 10) on p. 342 of <Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications>, 2011, by Albert W. Marshall, Ingram Olkin, and Barry C. Arnold, online at https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68276-1, which was pointed out by Matcha at Von Neumann's Trace Inequality for Multiple Matrices.
Now write
\begin{equation}
    G = X^T A X
\end{equation}
where $x_1, ..., x_n$ are the columns of $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$.
Then, by (I) and (II) for some orthogonal matrix $M$:
\begin{align*}
   \|G\|_* =& \|X^T A X\|_* \\
=& Tr(X^T A X M) \\
    \leq & \sum_i \sigma_i(A) \sigma_i(X)^2 \sigma_i(M) \\
\leq & \sigma_1(A) \sigma_1(M) \sum_i \sigma_i(X)^2  \\
    = & \|A\|_2 \|X\|_F^2 = n \|A\|_2 \\
\end{align*}
If anyone finds a flaw or gap, please point it out!
